# how use gridview as parent and detailview as child

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have two database both are two only two columns.
gidview and detailview connected with each one datbase.
i want to display detailview  with bind database when  i m select item of gridview.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would look at the Using Nested Repeaters article.  This lays out the basic concepts you will need for setting up a dataset with the proper relations.

You should be able to then modify this so that you're using a DataGrid with a TemplateColumn.  Use the concepts for embedding a nested repeater, but instead, nest the DetailVliew in the ItemTemplate.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306154

I should point out that there is an easier method based on the effect you want.  You don't need to nest the controls.    See this article:

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-10-cs.aspx